# SqlDependency not working

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, sqldependency

I'm using EF 6 with SQL Server 2012.

I'm trying to use `SqlDependency` to refresh my cached data, in a class library (DLL).

I have the following, based on whatever guides I found, but seems like it is not working, and I get no error.

- enabled broker service on the db
- created the broker queue, and the service

Using `sa` login.

I'm testing this whole thing through unit testing code, not sure maybe the notification is not instantaneous, my breakpoint in `SqlDependency.OnChange` never triggered.

But even if I purposely slow down the post-changes, `OnChange` is still not triggered.

Once I made relevant data changes, how can I know SQL Server is generating a notification in db?

*Update:*

Initially I found "master key encryption is required" in SQL log. By creating that key, the log no longer happened, but `OnChange` is still not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

After many trials, and based on 1 important article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events

1) After SqlDependency is initialized, must execute the SqlCommand, can simple just invoke sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery().

2) After OnChange event triggered, must remove the event handling, recreate a new SqlCommand and SqlDependency, rebind the event handling, and follow rule #1